# Meaning of ** (and other symbols) in a Symfony Glob Pattern

Tags: php, symfony, glob

A few years back Symfony introduced glob patterns for [importing](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-import-config-files-with-glob-patterns) and [loading](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-load-config-files-with-glob-patterns) configuration files.  You can see an example of this in the stock kernel class

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollectionBuilder $routes): void
{
    $confDir = $this->getProjectDir() . '/config';

    $routes->import($confDir . '/{routes}/*' . self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
    $routes->import($confDir . '/{routes}/' . $this->environment . '/**/*' . self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
    $routes->import($confDir . '/{routes}' . self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
}
```

Those glob patterns expand to look like this

```
$routes->import("/path/to/symfony/config/{routes}/*.{php,xml,yaml,yml}", ...
$routes->import("/path/to/symfony/config/{routes}/dev/**/*.{php,xml,yaml,yml}", ...
$routes->import("/path/to/symfony/config/{routes}.{php,xml,yaml,yml}", ...
```

This brings a few questions to mind.  First off -- what is the `**` pattern? That's not a standard [part of PHP's glob](https://www.php.net/glob) syntax. I presume by context it means "everything in this folder and all sub-folders", but I can't find official docs on Symfony's glob syntax to know for sure.

Other things about the patterns are odd -- like `{routes}`. Normally you put things in braces when you want to match a list -- but this uses braces with only one item in the list which makes me think I don't understand what's going on?

When I [go spelunking](https://github.com/symfony/config/blob/master/Loader/FileLoader.php#L96) in [the source code](https://github.com/symfony/config/blob/master/Resource/GlobResource.php#L94) the [methods involved](https://github.com/symfony/finder/blob/master/Glob.php#L48) are big ones and not the most intuitive to follow.

Is Symfony's glob syntax an implementation of a standard glob syntax? Or is it its own thing, and if so, what extra features does it have beyond the standard wildcards? (regexes? more special things like `**`? does a single word in a brace mean anything?)

Comment: This is analogous to Bash with `globstar` option enabled. So `/path/to/symfony/config/{routes}/dev/**/*.{php,xml,yaml,yml}` will get down to the `dev` directory and then search all subdirectories for `*.php`, `*.xml`, etc.

Comment: Useful, thank you @miken32!